# How to get the ID of a row on a table

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I want to get the id of a row on a table so that once delete button of that row has been clicked, that row will be deleted. Please help.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result !== false) {

echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
foreach($result as $row) {

  echo $row['id']. ' - '. $row['user_email']. ' - '. $row['user_password']. ' - '. $row['user_username'];

  echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-link'>Delete</button><br>";
 echo "</form>";


}
```

}

Comment: Please what you have tried!

Comment: add your code here!!

Comment: How does your table look like?

Comment: <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link delete-row' id="'.$row['id'].'">Delete</button><br>...use on click with .delete-row.

Comment: is it okay to call php inside script tag so that i can delete the row in the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="row11">
        <td>murali</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td><button>get data</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row12">
        <td>murali2</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td><button>get data</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        if(btn){
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            console.log(row[0]);

        }
    })
</script>
```